# .wlapp file deployment error in Worklight

Tags: mysql, ibm-mobilefirst

I am migrating a Worklight application from my development environment in Eclise to a Testing environment on Tomcat 7, with MySQL as my Worklight database.

I followed the instructions given @ [Worklight Guide](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/10_01_Moving_from_development_environment_to_stand-alone_QA_and_production_servers.pdf)  and [IBM Guide for setting up MySql for Worklight](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_setting_up_your_my_sql_database_manually.html).

When deploying via Worklight Console, the console deploys adapters without a problem, but while deploying the .wlapp files, there is a DB error:

**[ERROR while deploying .wlapp of size 4.5MB ]**

> Failed to deploy application 'XXXXXXXX.wlapp'. : Parameter of prepared
>   statement which is set through mysql_send_long_data() is longer than
>   'max_allowed_packet' bytes {prepstmnt 940490894 INSERT INTO
>   APP_SYNC_DATA (appDeployableKey, deployable, deployableHash,
>   lastPersistentPropertyChange) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) [params=(String)
>   jqmMultipageSite1-android-1.0, (InputStream)
>   java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@5083c762, (String)
>   4acdb5054a0bd4ec908ad282bb95d183bbbdd217, (long) 1369395093111]}
>   [code=1105, state=HY000]

**[ ERROR while deploying wlapp for iPhone of size 1.5 MB ]**

> Failed to deploy application 'xxxxxxxxx.wlapp'. : Data truncation:
>   Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'LAST_UPDATE_TIME' at row 1
>   {prepstmnt 362762411 INSERT INTO GADGETS (DISP_IN_GALLERY,
>   LAST_UPDATE_TIME, NAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?) [params=(int) 1, (Timestamp)
>   2013-05-24 17:10:06.322, (String) jqmMultipageSite1]} [code=0,
>   state=22001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty much straight forward. The deployment of the .wlapp files fails because the value of the property `max_allowed_packet` in MySQL is too low (by default it is 1MB).

It seems like the MySQL guide you've linked to misses some (important) steps.
Try these instructions:

1. Locate the file `my.ini` belonging to your MySQL installation
2. In it, find the section `[mysqld]`
3. Underneath the section name, paste this: `max_allowed_packet=500M`
4. Re-start the MySQL service
5. Re-deploy the .wlapp files

Deployment should now pass.

Comment: Thanks Idar. No Success though.
I changed the max_allowed_packet to 500 , and then to 1024. Both the errors mentioned above still persist.
I restarted MYSQL [ mysqladmin.exe --user=user --password=password shutdown  + Start Windows MYSQL Service ]

Comment: Couple of more things :
1. I have checked the MYSQL Windows service and it points to the location of ini file that I have made the changes above.
`C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" MySQL56`

2. I have installed the latest fix packs for Worklight as well.

Comment: The exact same errors? If not the same, please update the question.

Comment: I was able to get over the 'max_allowed_packet' error.Now the second error:
**Failed to deploy application 'xx.wlapp'. : Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'LAST_UPDATE_TIME' at row 1 {prepstmnt 24265963 INSERT INTO GADGETS (DISP_IN_GALLERY, LAST_UPDATE_TIME, NAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?) [params=(int) 1, (Timestamp) 2013-05-25 17:21:49.806, (String) xx]} [code=0, state=22001]**

is coming for all .wlapp uploads.It seems from the error that the INSERT statement is trying to put a datatype **TIMESTAMP** into a field that is of type **datetime**[LAST_UPDATE_TIME in gadgets table].

Comment: How did you solve the first issue? I'd try clearing the database from previous attempts made.

Comment: The .ini file is created in "Program Data" as well as "Program Files" in Windows 7. I was changing the incorrect .ini file. This command helped. 

** show variables like 'max_allowed_packet'; ** 

I have created the MySQL DB from the SQL scripts created from the installed Worklight server {create-worklight-mysql.sql} 

CREATE TABLE GADGETS (ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, DISP_IN_GALLERY BIT, ** LAST_UPDATE_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL**, NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID), UNIQUE UNQ_ (NAME)) ENGINE = innodb;

Comment: I suggest to take the second issue into its own question as this is becoming a bit lengthy. Mark this one as Answered and open a new question with the second issue, however I do think that you should try now to clear the database and try deployment again.

Comment: All the SQL issues resolved with MYSQL version 5.5.31.
Cheers!!