# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Fail to publish application to Application Center?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I have developed a Worklight application using Dojo 1.9 and tested it in my local machine and it is working fine. But when I tried to publish my application to IBM Worklight Application Center I have set-up in my application server, I am getting an Internal Server Error.

[image]

I also tried deploying the application directly to the appcenterconsole (there is an option to Add Application), but I am getting a message saying that my .apk file was not uploaded.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the first error/screen shot, but regarding the second one - what is the database you are using? If it is MySQL then you must edit your database settings to increase max size allowed.

Follow the instructions given in the answer to this question: [.wlapp file deployment error in Worklight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734471/wlapp-file-deployment-error-in-worklight)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Idan Adar.i tried deploying another .apk file (not developed from Worklight Environment) through appcenterconsole,it works fine.But its size is only 500KB.Worklight application .apk is around 2.5 MB. What is the need of MySql here.

Comment: There is no specific need for MySQL, rather I am ASKING you if MySQL is your database, because obviously you need one (a database). So I am asking, what is your database, if it's MySQL - try my suggestion.

Comment: Absolutely not possible. If you have installed Application Center, then you have also set up a database.

Comment: Is there any size limitation in Worklight Server.Is there any settings i need to change in my server.What are the other ways to deploy application to server.

Comment: You are not deploying to the Workligt Server. You are deploying to the Application Center database - Worklight Server and Application Center are SEPARATE ENTITIES.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37170/discussion-between-cyber-and-idan-adar)